# Ajax listener not work and fail to get log message in liferay

Tags: java, ajax, jsf-2, liferay

I am building a simple project using liferay jsf and had plan to insert `<f:ajax listener="#{jsfController.searchValidDestination}">` within `<h:selectOneMenu/>` in my view page. My problem is, i cant get result from method called from ajax listener. What i try so far is, I create a logger and insert this logger in each method and still, nothing happen. Did i miss something?

This is my `view.xhtml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<f:view xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<h:head />
<h:form>
    <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin-bottom:10px" cellpadding="5">
        <h:outputLabel for="oneWay" value="One way only" />
        <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="oneWay"
            value="#{flightSearchBean.oneWayOnly} ne true ? false : true" />
        <h:outputLabel for="fromAirport" value="From: "></h:outputLabel>
        <h:selectOneMenu id="fromAirport"
            value="#{flightSearchBean.selectedOrigin}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{jsfController.airportList}" var="airport"
                itemValue="#{airport.iataCode}"
                itemLabel="#{airport.cityAndIataCode}" />
            <f:ajax listener="#{jsfController.searchValidDestination}"></f:ajax>
        </h:selectOneMenu>
        <h:outputLabel for="toAirport" value="To : "></h:outputLabel>
        <h:selectOneMenu id="toAirport"
            value="#{flightSearchBean.selectedDestination}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{jsfController.airportList}" var="airport"
                itemValue="#{airport.iataCode}"
                itemLabel="#{airport.cityAndIataCode}" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>

        <h:outputLabel for="departureDate" value="Departure Date" />
        <p:calendar value="#{flightSearchBean.selectedDepartureDate}"
            id="departureDate" showOn="button" pattern="EEE, dd-MMM-yyyy" />
        <h:outputLabel for="returnDate" value="Return Date" />
        <p:calendar value="#{flightSearchBean.selectedReturnDate}"
            id="returnDate" showOn="button" pattern="EEE, dd-MMM-yyyy" />
    </h:panelGrid>
    <h:commandButton value="Search"
        action="#{jsfController.searchFlight}">
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
</f:view>
```

This is my controller class

```
public class JsfController implements Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JsfController.class);

@Inject
private transient FlightSearchBean flightSearchBean;

@Autowired
AirportApi airportApi;
@Autowired
RouteApi routeApi;
private List<Airport> airportList = null;

public AirportApi getAirportApi() {
    return airportApi;
}

public void setAirportApi(AirportApi airportApi) {
    this.airportApi = airportApi;
}

   public RouteApi getRouteApi() {
    return routeApi ;
}

public void setRouteApi (RouteApi routeApi ) {
    this.routeApi = routeApi ;
}

public List<Airport> getAirportList() {
    airportList = airportApi.findAllAirport();
    return airportList;
}

public void setAirportList(List<Airport> airportList) {
    this.airportList = airportList;
}

public FlightSearchBean getFlightSearchBean() {
    return flightSearchBean;
}

public void setFlightSearchBean(FlightSearchBean flightSearchBean) {
    this.flightSearchBean = flightSearchBean;
}

public void searchValidDestination(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) throws AbortProcessingException{
    logger.debug("Search flight with origin: "+flightSearchBean.getSelectedOrigin() );
    System.out.println(event.getPhaseId());
    airportList.clear();
}
    airportList.addAll(routeApi.findRoutes(flightSearchBean.getSelectedOrigin()));
}

public String searchFlight() {
    logger.debug("Search flight with origin: "+flightSearchBean.getSelectedOrigin()+" and destination: " + flightSearchBean.getSelectedDestination() );
            routeApi.
    return "success";
}

}
```

And this is my faces-config.xml (since this page not complete yet, I just only have view.xhtml). For scope, I used request scope first, but when I get error like, I change it into view.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<faces-config version="2.1" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_1.xsd">
<lifecycle>
    <phase-listener>com.liferay.faces.util.lifecycle.DebugPhaseListener</phase-listener>
    <phase-listener>com.liferay.faces.util.lifecycle.ViewScopePhaseListener</phase-listener>
</lifecycle>
<application>

<el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
</application>
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>jsfController</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.test.controller.JsfController</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>view</managed-bean-scope>
    <managed-property>
        <property-name>airportApi</property-name>
        <value>#{airportApi}</value>
    </managed-property>
</managed-bean>

<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/views/view.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>success</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/views/view.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>

</navigation-rule>
</faces-config>
```

I had post same thread into liferay forums, and I have cross-posted it here too.

Comment: Do you have `@ManagedBean(name = "jsfController")` and `@ViewScoped` on your `JsfController` class? Also you probably want an `h:body` tag in your view. You should also make sure that you are using the correct version of Liferay Faces according to the [Liferay Faces Version Scheme](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/liferay-faces-version-scheme-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-04-en).

Comment: In general cross-posting at the same time is generally frowned upon. However if you choose to do it anyway, please add a link of the other locations of your question in all copies. This is helpful for later answers to check that your question has not been answered elsewhere prior to writing an answer, and it is helpful for future readers to find more answers should any particular instance of the question not have attracted answers the reader finds useful.

Answer (score 1):

Change the method signature as below

```
public void searchValidDestination(AjaxBehaviorEvent event){}
```

Comment: I was try it and nothing change. *sorry just edited.

Comment: Have you tried giving event="change" in <f:ajax>. Also where's the close tag for your f:view

Comment: I did. I dont know, but i just wondering the problem is from liferay side.

Answer (score 0):

According to the JSF 2.2 [f:ajax](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserverfaces/2.2/vdldocs/facelets/f/ajax.html) documentation, your ajax listener method signature must match:

```
public void processAjaxBehavior(javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent event) throws javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException
```